# cron job/mysql event task

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm completely clueless as to do a cron job/mysql event task for some things in my database to be updated automatically every 24 hours.

Basically here's the 2 queries I need to be ran every 24 hours as soon as `users_stats` `DailyRespectPoints` hits '0'.

```
UPDATE user_stats SET DailyPetRespectPoints = '3' and 
UPDATE user_stats SET DailyRespectPoints = '3'
```

Those are what needs to be ran so that when someone uses all 3 of their `DailyRespectPoints`, it refills back to 3 in 24 hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could create trigger , which will be executed automatically when DailyRespectPoints hits '0'.

you can read more about the triggers here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

or you can write more details about your database/query-s and we can help you write the trigger

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Basically, I am working on a game where users get what's called "Daily Respect Points." I want it so every 24hours, they get refilled back to 3 since they start out with 3. But the thing is, some users may use them close to when the 24 hours comes. So it needs to be updated to 3 in the 24 hours that they use all 3. So basically say UserX uses 3 respect points and now has none, UserX has to wait 24 hours for his 3 respects to go back to '3'. And those 2 queries I posted are the ones that update '0' to '3' but I dont want to have to run it manually.

Comment: you want all the users` respect points to be updated all at once or you want them depending their use of respect point ?

Comment: Depending on their use of respect points. Because some users may use them at different times. So once they use theirs, they have to wait 24 hours to refill back to 3.

Comment: You cant update automatically exactly after 24 hours , 
but
there is a few ways you can do it
when user uses his/her last credit , you will store datetime within a row , 

after that , you can put in cronjob query that will update rows where now - last_used_time is more than 24 hours , but this wont be exact 24 hours , because cronjob will run with intervals , so this interval might be your delay after 24 hours and it is not good to run cronjob with little interval,

read bellow comment also

Comment: also you could do this this way
you will store current_points ,
after user uses point , if current_point was > 0 and become 1 , you will update last_used to current time , if current_point = 0 and now - last_used  > 24 hours update their point to 3 or whatever and then subtract the point user wants to use

i think this would be better to use ...

Answer (score 0):

First write a script that will perform the work you need done.  Based on your question, you will check some table value, then execute your two `UPDATE` steps.

After your script is tested and performs correctly, you can schedule it to run every day at some point in time using `cron` (probably `crontab`).